# JodaTime: Get DateTimeZone with offset xyz compared to utc

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, offset

I want to use org.joda.time.DateTime. It need the following params:

```
DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute, int millisOfSecond, DateTimeZone zone)
```

Now the problem is, that I need the DateTimeZone, but I only know the offset compared to UTC, but how can I build this DateTime without knowing the exact name? All I have is a long value (e.g. 50400000) with offset in millis. The other values like year, hour, seconds etc are given.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the offset, you can use [`DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forOffsetMillis(int)) to create a fixed-offset time zone.

That won't necessarily be the *real* time zone, but the offset alone isn't enough information to *tell* you the real time zone.

Comment: But all I have is a string with all parameters and a given offset. Additional I know if the offset is + or - compared to UTC. But I think this helps :-)

Comment: @user3280180: I've shown you the method you need to call to get a `DateTimeZone` for a given offset. That's what your question asked about... it's not clear what you mean by "a string with all parameters" but the question of "How can I get a `DateTimeZone` given only a UTC offset" is relatively straightforward.